# Printing elements from a for loop

Tags: java, swing, loops, for-loop

I am having a very strange problem, I have a method noOfPlayers that asks for the number of players in the game, Once I have the number of players in the game I ask for each of their names in turn. Once I have been given the name of the player a frame is created asking them to specify what counter they'd like to pick. When they click the purple gem (for testing purposes) it should print out the players name in the console but the for loop doesnt seem to work. Any idea how i'd get the loop to work correctly?

```
public class setupPlayers extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    int intOfPlayers, purpleClick = 0, orangeClick = 0, iceClick = 0, greenClick = 0;
    ArrayList<Player> arrayOfPlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    JButton purpleGemBTN, greenGemBTN, iceCubeBTN, orangeGemBTN;
    JFrame organisationPanel;
    JPanel titleChoiceCounter, counterSelector;
    ImageIcon finalCounter;
    private static Dialog d;

    public setupPlayers() {}

    public void noOfPlayers() {
        try {
            String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the number of players");
            intOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
            if (intOfPlayers > 4) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only 1-4 can play!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                noOfPlayers();
                intOfPlayers = 0;
            }

            for (int z = 0; z < intOfPlayers; z++) {
                String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player " + (z + 1) + " please input your name");
                chooseCounter();
                arrayOfPlayers.add(new Player(playerName, (z + 1), null, 0));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter the number of players, please enter the number of players", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            noOfPlayers();
        }
    }

    public void chooseCounter() {
        Frame window = new Frame();

        ImageIcon purpleGemImg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Documents\\pink.png");
        ImageIcon greenGemImg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Documents\\yellow.png");
        ImageIcon orangeGemImg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Documents\\brown.png");
        ImageIcon iceCubeImg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Documents\\white.png");

        d = new Dialog(window, "Please select your counter", true);
        d.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        d.setLocation(400, 300);
        d.setSize(500, 500);

        purpleGemBTN = new JButton("purple", purpleGemImg);
        greenGemBTN = new JButton(greenGemImg);
        orangeGemBTN = new JButton(orangeGemImg);
        iceCubeBTN = new JButton(iceCubeImg);

        purpleGemBTN.addActionListener(this);
        greenGemBTN.addActionListener(this);
        iceCubeBTN.addActionListener(this);
        orangeGemBTN.addActionListener(this);

        d.add(purpleGemBTN);
        d.add(greenGemBTN);
        d.add(orangeGemBTN);
        d.add(iceCubeBTN);

        d.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setupPlayers spObj = new setupPlayers();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton pressed = new JButton();
        pressed = (JButton) e.getSource();
        if (pressed.getText().equals("purple")) {
            for (int z = 0; z < arrayOfPlayers.size() - 1; z = z) {
                String currentPlayer = arrayOfPlayers.get(z).playerNme;
                System.out.println(currentPlayer);
            }
            d.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Future reference: when you say "it doesn't seem to work"  explain what should happen as well as what does happen.

Comment: I just noticed you're recursively calling `noOfPlayers();` I think you'll get some unexpected results from doing that.

Comment: How could I fix it so that if they enter an invalid string into number of players, keep asking for the number of players? that was the only way I could think to do it. And is this the reason the for loop isnt working ?

Comment: I would use a do-while loop. Maybe you recursed correctly, I don't know, I haven't ran the code.

Comment: a do while loop doesnt work just tested it. Once i enter number of players and all their names, it asks for number of players again AND still doesnt print properly

Comment: @Blueaddiction where is the code?

Comment: Being a university project, I didn't want to keep my full classes code on SO. Just in case I get accused for plagerism even though I've done 99 percent of the code myself . I will create a new class that somewhat reflects the old problem but I don't want the code I'm uploading to be the same as SO code

Comment: Anyone can see the edit log, so they would see your code anyway. I've reverted the deletion of your code because the problem was not clearly stated and it invalidates all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from your comments on the previous answers, I'm guessing your problem is more related to how you are recursively obtaining the names.

Here is a quick pair of methods that seem to achieve what you are wanting without recursion.

```
private ArrayList<Player> arrayOfPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
private int intOfPlayers;

public void noOfPlayers() {

    while (true) {
        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input the number of players");

        if (inputValue != null) { // Text was entered, cancel not clicked
            try {
                intOfPlayers = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
                if (intOfPlayers > 4 || intOfPlayers < 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only 1-4 can play!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    break; // stop asking for numbers
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a number!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                e.printStackTrace(); // never ignore errors, even if obvious
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quitting from number players input");
            System.exit(0); // Canceled the dialog, so quit the program
        }

    }

    for (int z = 0; z < intOfPlayers; z++) {
        String playerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player " + (z + 1) + " please input your name");
        if (playerName != null) {
            // chooseCounter(playerName);
            arrayOfPlayers.add(new Player(playerName, (z + 1), null, 0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Quitting from player " + (z + 1) + " name input");
            System.exit(0); // Canceled the dialog, so quit the program
        }
    }

    printPlayerNames();
}

private void printPlayerNames() {
    for (int z = 0; z < arrayOfPlayers.size(); z++) {
        String currentPlayer = arrayOfPlayers.get(z).playerNme;
        System.out.println(currentPlayer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will implement this code in the morning and feedback if there are errors! Thank you

Comment: Hey, I really appreicate the feedback the code worked, would it be possible to remove to remove everything but the for loop fix? I don't want to be accused of plagiarism. Also could you explain what happens when I use recursion why does it print in the way it does

Comment: The reason the recursion acts incorrectly is because when you call the function again, it correctly goes back to the top as you want, but when the function exits, it resumes the line after where you originally called the function, therefore adding duplicate names to the list. So, you are welcome to take the code, but change it if you are that worried about plagiarism. There really isn't that much to change, though, because all I did was take your variable names and reorganized them.

Comment: I would use `boolean` values for `<color>Taken`, then say `if (!<color>Taken) { <color>Taken = true; }`. Also, you just need to do `takenCounter++;` instead of `takenCounter = takenCounter++;` since `takenCounter++;` expands to `takenCounter = takenCounter + 1;`

Comment: Also stop getting trigger happy with your method calls. You're calling `chooseCounter` from the ActionListener, which if you do that you'll create a whole new frame with a new set of buttons. The purpose of the actionListener is to perform an action (set the player's avatars), not restart your app.

Comment: how could I effectively ask them to re-select their avatar if the one they selected was taken? I have no idea how to do it

Comment: The dialog will remain open as long as you don't set its visibility to false. You can close the dialog when they make a valid option. When an invalid option is selected, an error box pops up in front of the dialog. You already have that part. I should also mention that the `else` statement for the orange button is in the wrong place.

Comment: I fixed the orange button after posting the code, thanks for all the help its much appreciated ill do the rest alone now! again it means a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try to write this for loop:

```
  for (int z=0; z<arrayOfPlayers.size()-1;z=z){...
```

Like this:

```
   for (int z=0; z<arrayOfPlayers.size();z++){...
```

Increase the `z++` and remove `-1` from `arrayOfPlayers.size()-1` because the index `z` start from `0`:

Comment: I don't think 1 needs subtracted from size() here

Comment: When I try this method i get PlayerOne
PlayerOne
PlayerTwo
PlayerOne
PlayerTwo
PlayerThree

Comment: @Blueaddiction do you mean this method: actionPerformed

Comment: @abdhak I replaced the for loop I had in action performed with your for loop and it doesn't print properly

Answer (score 2):

or better with for each loop

```
    for(Player p : arrayOfPlayers)
    {
      String name = p.playerNme;
      System.out.println(name);
    }
```

Comment: So i added your code in place of mine, now if i wrote in the input to play with 4 people, and input the first name and clicked the purple gem when the frame popped up, then input second name when input popped up and clicked purple gem again... doing the same thing till i wrote all 4 players i get this on the command line output which is wrong PlayerOne
PlayerOne
PlayerTwo
PlayerOne
PlayerTwo
PlayerThree

Answer (score 0):

Your not iterating through the for loop `z++` not `z=z`:

```
for (int z=0; z<arrayOfPlayers.size()-1;z++){
    String currentPlayer = arrayOfPlayers.get(z).playerNme;
    System.out.println(currentPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have  `for (int z=0; z<arrayOfPlayers.size()-1;z=z)` you will iterate infinitely because `z` will always be equal to `0`.

Try to change the `z=z` to `z++` so that the iteration ends once `z = arrayOfPlayers.size()-1`.

your code will be:

```
for (int z=0; z<arrayOfPlayers.size();z++){
    String currentPlayer = arrayOfPlayers.get(z).playerNme;
    System.out.println(currentPlayer);
}
```